# How do I tell what are the ids and classes of a rail html.erb component?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, class

So in the tutorial example in Agile Web Development v.4, I was trying to change the css style of the table populated by line_items in the cart menu. So I thought the id should be #cart, but apparently the id should be #store? I don't know how to access the id information of a particular .html.erb block.

Comment: Could you paste at least a snippet representing what you're trying to fix? Not everyone is familiar with that source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You access the id information in an .html.erb file just as you would in a normal .html file, it is still just basic HTML. You would set the id of your  or  just like you would in normal HTML. Just set the id property of your HTML element, and add your CSS for it.